# What are the steps to install a LAMP configuration under Gentoo

Tags: linux, php, gentoo, lamp

All of the guides I could find online were from 2004 and they no longer work. I am stumped.

Could someone create a step by step guide?  I have Apache working, but PHP does not work.

Comment: You do not say what does not work. Did you install the php-mod for apache?

Comment: This is really a Server Fault question.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be too complicated. Make sure you've done the following (or equivalent commands):

```
# Make sure PHP has the apache2 USE flag set
echo "dev-lang/php apache2" >> /etc/portage/package.use
# Install packages
emerge www-server/apache dev-lang/php
```

then edit `/etc/conf.d/apache2` to include `-D PHP5` in `APACHE2_OPTS`, (re)start Apache, and you should be good to go.

If you've accounted for all that, you'll need to provide more specific information about what problems you're having in the question, as txwikinger pointed out.